# Crystal Reports Parameter Case Change

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2010

I would like to mask a parameter within Crystal reports.

Currently I have a number that I need to change to a string.

So for example the 4 data types in this field are 
1
2
3
4

I use

case 1:"yes"
case 2:"No"
case 3:"Maybe"
case 4:"approval"

Now I need to filter it using a dynamic parameter however it displays in the drop down as 
1 2 3 4

how can I make it show as it does when I run the report.

Comment: Can you explain more... a screenshot would help

Comment: @Siva, I dont have a screenshot with me, but I have tried to explain it better above.

Comment: so you want to mask the numbers to strings in parameter? you have as numbers in database and in CR you are changing it to string... now you want those strings in dynamic paramter? is this correct?

Comment: To the extent I know when you use dynamic parameter the data displayed in parameter is from database... so when you convert to String that may not be possible in showing dynamic parameter

Comment: one way out would be give parameter as `static` as string and in CR you mask those to number and use in report.

Comment: are you using a SQL or ORACLE Stored Procedure to show your report???

Comment: I had the same problem and here is the answer: [How to pass the parameter's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862733/crystal-report-invalid-index-exception-from-hresult-0x8002000b-disp-e-badin/35954722#35954722)

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one way to solve it the most efficient is from the DB, in the select query instead of select number use :

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Number = 1 THEN 'Yes'
  CASE WHEN Number = 2 THEN 'No'
  CASE WHEN Number = 3 THEN 'Maybe'
  CASE WHEN Number = 4 THEN  'Approval' AS Number
```

OR you can add a parameter value to your report e.g @Number with String Datatype and fill it from the code behind

```
Select Case dropdownlist.selectedvalue
      Case 1
       rpt.SetParameterValue("@Number", "Yes")

      Case 2
       rpt.SetParameterValue("@Number", "No")

      Case 3
       rpt.SetParameterValue("@Number", "Maybe")

      Case 4
       rpt.SetParameterValue("@Number", "Approval")
```

Or from the report itself right click on the field Number in report and select Format Object and select the formula of a property called (Display String)
and add this code:

```
 If {Report Field} = 1 THEN 
 {Report Field} = 'Yes'
 ELSE 
 IF {Report Field} = 2 THEN
 {Report Field} = 'No'
 ELSE {Report Field} = 3 THEN
 {Report Field} = 'Maybe'
 ELSE
 IF {Report Field} = 4 THEN
 {Report Field} = 'Approval'
```

and Save your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add 4 default values to the parameter prompt

```
Value  Description
1      "yes"
2      "No"
3      "Maybe"
4      "approval"
```

Then select the flag show only description. In the parameter dialog you should see a drop down with the 4 strings but you receive one of the 4 numbers.